# Connection timeout at SMTPConnection._formatError

Tags: node.js, email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, nodemailer

I am getting this error in production when the GCP VM instance tries to send mail, while it works locally.

{
"textPayload": "Error: Connection timeout\n    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)\n    at SMTPConnection._onError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)\n    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:229:22)\n    at listOnTimeout
}

```
const transporter = createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "user",
      pass: "pass", // gmail pass
    },
  });
```

I have tried the App password too.

Comment: Did you allow the port 465 in your firewall rules? Did you read this documentation? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#email_custom_port

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have enabled this rule but still no success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem was the firewall and after many attempts issue still was not fixed. So I created a cloud function to send emails.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34697608)